# Change variable inside of the terminal in Java

Tags: java, terminal

I run a *.jar file in the Terminal with:

```
java -jar *.jar
```

is it possible to change a variable inside of this jar over the terminal like for example this:

```
java -jar *.jar -changevar test = "5"
```

or something like this.

Thanks for answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call `java -jar someJarFile.jar`, the main class gets loaded and your `main` function is called. Any arguments passed via the command line after the `java -jar someJarFile.jar` bit get passed into your main function in the String array called `args`. From there you would parse accordingly. Take a look at the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/cmdLineArgs.html) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably want to just pass the variable in as an argument to your "main" function.

See [the official documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/cmdLineArgs.html) for some examples.